# How to utilise pymssql after Upgrading from Python 3.4 to 3.7? Unable to remove error

Tags: error-handling, python-3.4, python-3.7

My Python application uses the pymssql module to connect and edit SQL data in forms. I upgraded to Python 3.7 and I receive the following error:

"DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 appication."

I have the 64bit win32 version of Python 3.7. I can't seem to resolve this. Does pymssql work with Python 3.7?

I uninstalled and reinstalled both Python and pymssql to ensure I have latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to completely unisntall Python 3.7 and pip, then delete the Python folder, and reinstall. I used the advanced install settings which puts Python in C:\Program Files. The only difference now is I need admin permissions to pip install/update etc but that's ok.